# How can I add comments at the top of data file that I have created using savetxt function in python 3.0?

Tags: python-3.x

Using the savetxt function, I created a data file named as 'output.dat' to which two arrays were written as two different columns. So the file output.dat contains 2 columns of data. Now I want to add headings at the top of each column that would help me to remind what the file contains when I refer back the file later. Say, I want to put the heading 'Time' on the top of the first column and 'Voltage' on the top of the second. How can I do this?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for CSV with a header.

Comment: not CSV. My output is a text file created using savetxt function

Comment: CSV is a text file format, with an optional header.

Comment: My output file has got the extension .dat and not .csv.

Comment: What format is ``.dat``? Does it *have* to be ``.dat``? Note that your question says the extension is ``.txt``.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Now the extension is corrected as .dat. It is just a data file, which as I said, contains two columns of data.

Comment: So what is stopping you from writing CSV format to ``output.dat``? The format you describe appears to match CSV, whether that is what you call the file or not. Otherwise, please clarify what format you desire.

Comment: As I said, I was able to create the file 'output.dat' with two columns of data. What I need to know is how to add a header to each column of data written into the file.